# $a$, $b$ such that root of $s(t)$ is in $[a, b]$

Tags: calculus

Let: $$s(t) = s_0 - \alpha gt + \alpha^2g(1-e^{\frac{-t}\alpha}),\quad s_0, \alpha, g, t>0$$

By monotonicity and the existence of zeroes theorem I can prove that $\exists!\xi : s(\xi) = 0$

I need to find $a, b : \xi \in [a, b]$.

- I found a candidate for $a$ by setting $a = \dfrac{s_0}{\alpha g} \implies s(a) = \not s_0 - \not s_0 + \underbrace{\alpha^2g}_{>0} \big( 1 - \underbrace{e^{\frac{-s_0}{\alpha g}}}_{<1} \big)>0$
- I have not managed to find any candidate for $b$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+for+t+in+0+%3D+s+%2B+a+g+t+%2B+a%5E2+g+%281+-+e%5E%28-t%2Fa%29%29

Comment: Thanks christian, I can use Wolfram Alpha as well.

Comment: I need an upper estimate of the root, not the root itself, I need the interval to apply an iterative method.

Comment: Rearrange WA's solution $t = W \left( -\exp \left(-1 -\frac{s_0}{\alpha^2g} \right) \right) + \frac{s_0}{\alpha^2g} + 1$ and substitute $x := \frac{s_0}{\alpha^2g}$ we get $t=W \left( e^{-x - 1} \right) + x + 1$ which is in $(0, \infty)$ because $x > 0$

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the product log function, and I don't think it's a prerequisite for the (numerical analysis) book I got this exercise from, still, thanks for now. Do you think it is possible to find a simpler interval or is that as simple as it gets?